# modrewrite чпу url

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

Здравствуйте! Не могу разобраться как можно описать всё одним правилом. И возможно ли это вообще. Имеются товары в каталоге к каждому создана чпу вида catalog/odezjda/kofta_1 которая должна трансформироваться в product.php?id=1

Намучал такое правило ^catalog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)_?$ product.php?id=$1 [L,QSA] оно конечно не работает.

Не хочется размножать .htaccess до 6 мегабайт и описывать там каждую ссылку отдельно. Что я делаю не так?(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для номера товара вы как раз не указали группу захвата.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^catalog/[^/]+/[^/]+_(\d+)$ product.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```